Json annotations used in Java mostly
I have data received from DB in JSON format, but I have to align all the fields in a proper position like below:
{
"Name":"Maveric",
"Age":"26",
"Add":"22 Boston Street"
}

I have tried this below and to assign the response fields in proper position.
@JsonPropertyOrder({"Name","Age","Add"})

but it's not working as expected. Every time, fields are getting different positions.

@rjdkolb Did you mean serialize and deserialize?

Can you add the code you use to serialize and deserialize. (I'll blame autocorrect, haha)

i got my solution sorry for posting late.
here below is the JSON annotation for some solution.
`@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)`  ignore Null fields

`@JsonProperty("maximum")` Map next Api JSON Data(MaximuM) value to you Java bean object (max)
private String max;

private String date;    
@JsonProperty(index=1) Return json response date feild on 1 index/position
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String string) {
        date = string;
    }

